# Adding array elements to a PSObject

Tags: arrays, powershell, psobject

Preface: I haven't any formal training with script writing. So I'm sure many of you will be banging you head against the table wondering what I'm doing.

I am working to gather information on our current catalog of Teams sites, and respective site owners. I have a PS script to gather the list of sites, then it loops through each site to get list of owners. After I gather that owner list (stored in a var) I loop through that var to get the user name and store each user name in an array as a new element. That element is then used later when adding a new member to a PSObject so I can export the results to a CSV. Here's a bit of the code;

```
#Var's
    $Count = 1
    $TSO = New-Object PSObject
    $SiteOwner = @("SiteOwner0","SiteOwner1","SiteOwner2","SiteOwner3","SiteOwner4","SiteOwner5","SiteOwner6","SiteOwner7") #Array to create column headers in the CSV
    
#STEP 1: Get a list of the sites
    $Sites = get-team | sort-object DisplayName

#STEP 2: Get a list of the owners of the different sites
    FOREACH ($i in $Sites){
            $h = Get-TeamUser -GroupID $i.GroupID | Where {$_.role -eq "Owner"}
            $Count += 1

            Write-Host . -ForeGroundColor "Cyan" -NoNewLine
            #Add the new columns to $TSO
            $TSO | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SiteName" -Value $i.DisplayName -Force
            $TSO | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "GroupOwner" -Value $i.Description -Force
            $TSO | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Visibility" -Value $i.Visibility -Force
            $TSO | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Archived" -Value $i.Archived -Force
            $TSO | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SiteEmail" -Value $i.MailNickname -Force

            #loop through each member to discover the assigned role
            FOREACH ($o in $h){
                Write-Host . -ForeGroundColor "Cyan" -NoNewLine
                #Build the dynamics of the owners before passing to $TSO
                $OHolder += $o.user
                } #END NESTED FOREACH
                
                #Handle BLANK elements in the $OHolder array
                #The number 8 is the number of array elements we need a value for
                $Comp = 0
                
                While($Comp -lt 8){
                
                If($OHolder[$Comp] -ne $null){
                    $TSO | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $SiteOwner[$Comp] -Value $OHolder[$Comp] -Force
                    }
                ELSEIF(-not ($OHolder[$Comp])){
                    $OHolder[$Comp] = "NA"
                    $TSO | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $SiteOwner[$Comp] -Value $OHolder[$Comp] -Force
                    }
                    
                    #Increment the $Comp
                    $Comp += 1
                    
                }#END WHILE

                #Resetting the $Comp outside the loop
                $Comp = 0
#************* END STEP 2 *************************
            
            #Squirt out the info to a CSV
            $TSO | Export-CSV -Path $OPathOut -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force
            
            #Reset the $OHOLDER Array
            $OHolder = @()
    } #END FOREACH
```

My problem is this; When adding the site owner to the PSObject for siteowner (`$TSO | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $SiteOwner[$Comp] -Value $OHolder[$Comp] -Force`) it's counting each character of the value as an element.

For example: `$OHolder` will have two elements, `$OHolder[0]` is supposed to equal "doe@domain.com" and `$OHolder[1]` is suppose to equal "john@domain.com". What actually happens is the length of the array becomes 29 (for each character) rather than 2.

How can I add the users to the PSObject as intended? Right now the output will have:

```
SiteOwner0 | SiteOwner1 | SiteOwner2
d          | o          | e
@          |d           |o
```

Comment: Hi, can you add a sample of the expected output as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `+=` to add items to an array. It is inefficient if the arrays become large. A new array is created each time after the current array contents are read into memory. You can simply output each item inside of the `foreach` and assign the array variable to the `foreach` output.

```
$OHolder = @(FOREACH ($o in $h){
    Write-Host . -ForeGroundColor "Cyan" -NoNewLine
    #Build the dynamics of the owners before passing to $TSO
    $o.user # Output 
})
```

In the simplistic example above, a loop is likely not even necessary as `$OHolder = ,$h.user` should suffice in PowerShell v3+.

Comment: Winner, winner - chicken dinner! That works great! If there is a single owner of a site, it's still splitting the UPN into individual element. So, for example, a length of 14 instead of 1. I'll get that figured out, but the rest works exactly as it should. Thanks!

Comment: Use `$OHolder = @( FOREACH ($o in $h){ $o.user })` to ensure that `$OHolder` is an array even if `$h` is scalar (or even null or empty)…

Comment: @Dalebert, I've added JosefZ's suggestion, which should add consistency when there is only one element.

Comment: OK, I'll add that and run it again to see what happens. I'll report back what happens.

Comment: JosefZ's suggestion worked perfectly. It is now adding the site owners to the respective colums correctly even if it is a single account. Thanks a lot for the help, guys. I learned a couple things and it is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining $OHolder variable before using += operator.

By default powershell seems to define a string variable in this case.

```
$undefVar = $null
$undefVar += "test"
$undefVar += "some"
# content of $undefVar is now testsome
```

Try to move `$OHolder = @()` before the loop `FOREACH ($o in $h){`

Comment: Oh, sorry. It is instantiated above, but I neglected to include it in my code snippet to you.